# Run Jenkins pipeline nightly continuously

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, nightly-build

I'm using Jenkins for OnCommit and Nightly Builds. My Build Trigger is for example at the weekend:

```
H/25 * * * 0,6
```

or from Monday to Friday:

```
H/25 0-5 * * *
```

The nightly build runs every 25 minutes.

But this way I can't use the time effectively and if there are changes to the build length I always have to adjust it.

How can I make a build run permanently from 8pm to 6am for example. As soon as the first build is finished, the next one should start. Then at 6am the last build starts.

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** How can I make a build run permanently from 8pm to 6am for example. As soon as the first build is finished, the next one should start. Then at 6am the last build starts

**A:** This step should work without jump through cron hoops. It [triggers the build with a delay](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/ParameterizedJobMixIn.ParameterizedJob.html#doBuild-org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerRequest-org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerResponse-jenkins.util.TimeDuration-) of `quietPeriod` which is the **number of seconds to delay** before starting.  This avoids the use of a scheduled (cron) job and instead just keeps calling itself.

Essentially, the job will continuously trigger itself between `hourStart .. hourEnd`, but after `hourEnd`, will add a block delay of seconds to the next iteration. You can do your own time math for more precision.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }

    stages {
        stage('running') {
            steps {
                echo "running job"
                sleep 5
            }
        }
        stage('run again?') {
        steps {
            script {
                currHour = new Date().format("HH").toInteger()
                hourStart = 20  // Start hour of run window ie: 0600 hr
                hourStop = 6    // End hour of run window ie: 2000 hr
                sph = 60* 60    // seconds per hour
                if (currHour > hourStop && currHour < hourStart ) sleepInterval  = ( hourStart - currHour ) * sph
            }
            echo "quietPeriod: $sleepInterval"
            build wait: false, quietPeriod: sleepInterval, job: "${JOB_NAME}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The downside is if the system stops, the job will not start on it's own ( you can work around that via [init.groovy](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/groovy-hook-scripts/)* ). The benefits are when the last existing job completes, it frees the executor; and you can stop the job at any time and not worry about it launching via cron.

**NOTE:** In Jenkins > 2.277.1, the following warning appears, not sure why:
[JENKINS-65426](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-65426) "*message in pipeline: [withMaven] Infinite loop of job triggers*" has been raised to address.

> [withMaven] WARNING abort infinite build trigger loop. Please consider
> opening a Jira issue: Infinite loop of job triggers

* add to init.groovy: `Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('folder_name/job_name').schedulebuild2(0)`

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

I am not necessarily recommending this solution but you could create a pipeline with a stage that calls itself between certain hours. You would probably need to disable concurrent executions and configure the build declarative to not wait and not propagate errors.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }
    
    
    stages {
        stage('output') {
            steps {
                echo 'I am doing something'
            }
        }
        
        stage('run again?') {
            steps {
                script {
                    /*
                     * You will need to write the Groovy code for now, start, and end
                     * Then you can compare the times and build a self calling pipeline
                     */
                    if ( now.after(start.time) && now.before(end.time) ) {
                        build wait: false, propagate: false, job: "${env.JOB_NAME}"
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```